# Access Denied for Users Special Folder

Tags: c#, special-folders

I Need to get users special folders size and remove unnecessary files. I have Administrator access, but in the first place  i receive access denied exception.
my code is

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var basePath = @"C:\Users";

        DirectoryInfo basePathInfo = new DirectoryInfo(basePath);
        var usersDirectories = basePathInfo.GetDirectories();

        foreach (var directory in usersDirectories)
        {
            foreach (var dir in directory.GetDirectories())
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"{dir} : {DirSize(dir)} Bytes");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d)
    {
        // Add file sizes.
        FileInfo[] fis = d.GetFiles();
        long size = fis.Sum(fi => fi.Length);

        // Add subdirectory sizes.
        DirectoryInfo[] dis = d.GetDirectories();
        size += dis.Sum(di => DirSize(di));

        return size;
    }
```

i tried some folders and found out that i cant read data form below folders

AppData

Application Data

Cookies

Documents

Local Settings

My Documents

NetHood

PrintHood

Recent

SendTo

Start Menu

Templates

I Also Added a manifest file  and  use this tag for run as administrator

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Please help, what can I do?

Thanks for your Time.

Comment: Is your application running `As Administrator`?

Comment: yes i try it too. also i added a manifest file and use this tag <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: Are you working in a Cooperate Network.  There are different admin account that are controlled by Group Policies which may prevent you from accessing folders.  Can you access these folder using a Windows Explorer?  If you can then the executable is not running with Admin Privileges.  The default is using your normal credentials.

Comment: I Tested the above code in these conditions:
my local account on my pc,
administrator account on my pc,
my account on domain,
administrator on server.
all of these modes made exception access denied

Comment: Admin privileges don't mean, you have rights to read everything, but you can get them. So first check if you have read access, if not get it.